# using the php date/time classes I'm trying to get certain specific days

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to find the right string to modify a DateTime object. I have a recurring calendar object:

Currently finding 'this date of next month' is easy enough: $start_date->modify('+1 month');

However, I am also looking to find 'this day of next month' and 'this day of next year'.

Couldn't find the relevant strings.
Cheers

EDIT:

So for example if we take the 2010-09-21 as the start date:

```
$start_date = new DateTime(20100921);
```

Finding the current DATE of the next month (numerical representation) would be:

```
$start_date->modify('+1 month');
```

However finding the current DAY of the next month (textual representation) is causing me more troubles.

```
This date is the third tuesday of this month - next month the third tuesday is the 19th
```

Comment: Please clarify (probably with small examples) what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the difference between "this date of next month" and "this day of next month"?

Comment: please make a pseudo-code example (like when you would call the function) with some example input and the expected output.

Comment: I see now! Hmm, that is tough. It will require a custom programmed function, for sure. Interested to see what comes up

Comment: cheers, well I'll continue with it then, good to know that I wouldn't be working through something for which there is already a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this for the 'same day next month':

```
<?php

switch(floor(date("d") / 7)) {
  case 0:
    $which = "first";
    break;
  case 1:
    $which = "second";
    break;
  case 2:
    $which = "third";
    break;
  case 3:
    $which = "fourth";
    break;
  case 4:
    $which = "fifth";
    break;
}

echo date("c", strtotime(sprintf("%s %s of +1 month", $which, date("l"))));
```

I dunno if the same works for 'Same day next year' (`fiftysecond thuesday of +1 year`), but you could also calculate it if you know which day the year starts with and then use `mktime()`.